# Выполнение Python функции при нажатии на кнопку в админке Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. 
Необходимо реализовать следующий функционал:
При нажатии на определенную кнопку в джанго админке, должна выполняться функция на питоне, которая заходит на сервер, цепляет некоторые значения и возвращает их. 
Реально ли реализовать такое чисто на джанге? Если да, то в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: Для админки можно также добавлять views и шаблоны, см. [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотреть нужно в сторону интеграции с JS + AJAX. Других способов интерактивного взаимодействия без перезагрузки страницы с биндингом на горячие клавиши нет.

В сети полно разных рецептов о подобной интеграции. Посмотри хотя бы [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/search/?q=Django%20AJAX#h). И о горячих клавишах [там тоже есть](https://habr.com/ru/post/19003/)